# Graduate Commutative algebra book or lecture notes in German

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra, mathematical-german

It may look strange but I am looking for a Graduate level book / lecture notes on Commutative algebra in German.
I wish the content to be as close as it is possible to Eisenbud's "Commutative Algebra with a view towards Algebraic Geometry".

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kunz's *[Einführung in die kommutative Algebra und algebraische Geometrie](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783528072469)* is fairly standard, and (as far as I can tell) corresponds quite neatly to the book by Eisenbud. If you're looking for something freely available online, I believe [this *Skript*](http://home.mathematik.uni-freiburg.de/soergel/Skripten/XXKAG.pdf) (lecture notes) is quite comprehensive.

Comment: Briliant! Thank you very much.
At first look I like the notes very much.

Comment: @EvgenyKuznetsov no problem :)

Comment: Since no other answers were posted I accept the existing one. Thank you a lot.